# Apache rewrite: file not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am working on an application where I use apache's .htaccess to rewrite URL's to different modules in my application. When I try and browse to my application, I get the following error:

> The requested URL /var/www/dynamicsuite/index.php was not found on this server.

but /var/www/dynamicsuite/index.php does exist! I tried to chmod 777 to see if it was an issue with permissions, but it still didn't work.

Here is the general file layout and what I am trying to accomplish:

```
/var/www/app                 - Main Directory
/var/www/app/index.php       - This is what I rewrite too
/var/www/app/modules/login   - The login form
/var/www/app/modules/home    - The homepage on login
/var/www/app/modules/error   - Error page if something goes wrong
```

When a user goes to the application, it will see if they are logged in or not and redirect them to the proper module. I use mod_rewrite because I don't want the users to have to specify a long URL such as *mysite.com/app/modules/login*. Instead I am making it so it is *mysite.com/app/login*. Everything after the module name in the URL I want to procces as variables using a class/method I have written. Example:

```
mysite.com/app/error/404/time/user/etc
```

vs

```
mysite.com/app/modules/error?error=404&time=12345&user=username&etc=asdf
```

Here is the code I am using in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,PT]

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Note: I am using the PT flag because I am using alias's for the application.

Using Ubuntu 14.04 with apache2, mod_rewrite, mod_alias

You can see it live here:

> https://test.walnutcreekhardware.com/ds/

Here are the other files that are used:

**config**

```
$cfg["install_dir"] = array("ds", "employee", "dynamicsuite");
```

**index.php**

```
// Required Scripts
require_once("config/config.php");

function __autoload($class) {
    require_once("core/lib/$class.class.php");
}

if(!dsDatabase::dbCheck()) {
    dsInstance::genericError(1);
    exit;
}

// Process the URI and direct the user to the proper module
elseif(!isSet(dsInstance::getUri()[0])){

    // If a session if found, skip the login page and render the homepage
    if(dsSession::checkSession() === true) {
        header("Location: home");
    }

    // If no session is found, render the login page
    else {
        header("Location: login");
    }

}

// If the module exists, render it
elseif(file_exists("modules/" . dsInstance::getUri()[0])) {
    require_once("modules/" . dsInstance::getUri()[0] . "/index.php");
}

// If no conditions are met, render the error page
else {
    dsInstance::genericError(404);
}
```

**getUri() function:**

```
public static function getUri() {

    global $cfg;

    if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "?") != false) {
        $uri = explode("/",      trim(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],0,strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"?")),"/"));
    } else {
        $uri = explode("/", trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/"));
    }

    $search = in_array($uri[0], $cfg["install_dir"]);

    if($search === true) {
        return array_splice($uri, 1, count($uri));
    } else {
        return $uri[0];
    }

}
```

**dbCheck() function:**

```
public static function dbCheck() {

    global $cfg;

    try {

        $db = new PDO($cfg['db_type'] . ":host=" .
                      $cfg['db_host'] . ";dbname=" .
                      $cfg['db_name'],
                      $cfg['db_user'],
                      $cfg['db_pass']);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

**checkSession() function:**

```
public static function checkSession() {

    if(isSet($_SESSION["DS_SESSION"])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**genericError() function:**

```
public static function genericError($code) {
    $location = dsInstance::getUri()[0];
    $time = time();
    header("Location: error/$code/$location/$time");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: TL;DR... Trust the error message. You think the file is there, but the path you are giving is clearly not working for Apache... Apache is looking for files from the web document root, is `var` right under the document root?

Comment: The file in question is below the web root and I have an alias set up to point to it. The application is one directory down from the web root. (App: /var/www | Web Root: /var/www/html). The file in the error it gives does exist, although I browse to it using an alias.

Comment: From what you're saying, it sounds to me like the web root (i.e. publicly accessible files) is `/var/www/html`, therefore there is no way for Apache to return `/var/www/dynamicsuite/index.php`. That file would have to be somewhere below `html`

Comment: Normally you are correct, but I have made an alias to let apache access it, here is the cfg http://lightpaste.com/paste/BznpldnX.

Comment: How about trying it without the alias for a moment?

Comment: That seems to do it! It works when I just put it in the web root, although now I need to figure out how to make it work with the alias. I thought that was the purpose of the PT flag when using rewrite? PS: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the issue (Thanks to zx81 for narrowing down the problem to the alias!)

By adding the mod_rewrite directive **RewriteBase** to my .*htaccess* file it now seems to work as intended.

Comment: Spot on. For the next person; If you're using "alias" to expose a folder (like a public or web folder), you'll need "RewriteBase".

Comment: @txyoji thanks much, but its odd since it outputs the exact path which exactly fits, yet it wont find it without sort of absolute base